# Mysterious Black Bars appearing on UIWebView resize

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, mask

When a user resizes a `UIWebView` within my application, black, empty spaces appear over the webpage at the sides of the webview.

I have tried the following solutions:

- Setting the UIWebViews color to non opaque and clearColor()
- Removing the UIWebView from the view and superview and adding it back.
- Refreshing the page on resize.
- Animating the resize.
- Creating a new window and removing the old one on resize.
- Resizing the page on resize.
- Using `autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]`

Absolutely nothing works. The black bars always appear and will never go away. Certain HTML elements are not affected by the bars (such as background images on pages) but I cannot find any solution myself or on the web. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer: A UIWebView must be resized by integers, or else it will truncate the page contents to what ever its new size is.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day!

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same behavior with UIWebView even when width and height are forced to integers. As I repeatedly resize, the black bars get wider. Did you actually end up doing some combination of this solution with others mentioned in the original question?

Comment: and if you keep going, pieces of the displayed page start appearing in the wrong place. It looks like some internal piece of code has cached the wrong size, and is maintaining it wrongly. The only solution I found so far is to keep it at 100% of screen width

Comment: Perhaps its not just integer, but to the nearest 2/4/8 pixels?